# How to fix Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class log does not exist'?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, windows-server-2012-r2

I am facing an issue with composer on **Windows Server 20012 R2**. I am trying to deploy a website and every time I run `composer install` or `composer update` I get the following:

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> php artisan optimize
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

And when I checked the **php error log** I find the following:

```
[17-Jul-2016 08:04:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class log does not exist' in C:\PATH_TO_PROJECT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:734
Stack trace:
#0 C:\PATH_TO_PROJECT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(734): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 C:\PATH_TO_PROJECT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
#2 C:\PATH_TO_PROJECT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
#3 C:\PATH_TO_PROJECT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(849): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Psr\\Log\\LoggerI...')
#4 C:\PATH_TO_PROJECT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\ in C:\PATH_TO_PROJECT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 734
```

When I try the same project on an **Ubuntu server** everything works fin! I have tried every answer i could find on the internet, but nothing worked for me. Any advise on how to solve this? And why it is happening?

The windows server PHP version is 5.6.

**composer.json** file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "greggilbert/recaptcha": "2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
        "vsch/laravel-translation-manager": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
         "files": ["app/Http/Helpers/helpers.php"]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed APP_NAME value in .env file like "Example App" and got an error, so I used double quotes and its working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by removing any space in the values in the **.env** file e.g.:

```
MAIL_PORT= 587
MAIL_FROM_NAME=ABC Medical
```

to:

```
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_FROM_NAME=ABCMedical
```

Or by using quotes:

```
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_FROM_NAME="ABC Medical"
```

Comment: Thanks! it resolved my issue.

Anyway is there a way to add spaces in .env file?

Comment: @HiranD.AWalawage try wrapping the values in quotes.

Comment: Thanks! It does the miracle.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when passing values with spaces in `.env` without quotes, I fixed it by wrapping the values in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

have you try
`composer dump-autoload`?

you might add a class without dump-autoload

Comment: @Waqleh This is cause by the code, find out where you has use the class log

Answer (score 0):

Most common reasons I can think of for this error to occur are the following:

1. Log class is called in a scope where it is not included with the USE statement.
2. A config file contains (parse) errors, which in turn does not allow your application to find the Log class. Check the files loaded early on in Laravel such as app.php.