# Error while trying to run docker command in Attendize

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to install attendize from [here](https://github.com/Attendize/Attendize)

I am trying to run this docker environment [link](https://github.com/Attendize/Attendize#docker-dev-environment) 
Works fine everything until

```
docker-compose build
```

Now, When I try to run,

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app composer/composer install
```

I get following errors

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(734): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(630): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
#2 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
#3 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(848): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
#4 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(803): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(772): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
#6 /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(630): Illuminat in /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 734
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

I tried googling about this error and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419182/how-to-fix-uncaught-exception-reflectionexception-with-message-class-log-does)

According to which, removing white spaces in `.env` should fix the error. But didn't work for me.

Can someone please tell how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: How does your `.env` look like now?

Comment: DB_TYPE=pgsql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=attendize
DB_USERNAME=attendize
DB_PASSWORD=attendize

Comment: i suggest you to combine the two of docker files and build custom image out of it. i would do it for you but it has a lot of images and my internet is slow

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Docker box available on the Attendize Github page that will help you get up and running more quickly.